# To showing image files on Android , I would like to know whether this way

Tags: android

I have a question , Showing image on android~

I will try to send converted files to ByteArray into a single inputStream to android

my plan is

1. Files convert to byte[] (On Server)
2. Add a separator for each converted file. and Put them in the 
   single response.Outstream (On Server)
3. Get the InputStream (On android)
4. Using separator , Get a each byteArray from InputStream and convert them to
   bitmap file Using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` and not saved them
   (On android)

Sever :

```
OutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
imageDownload_fewfiles aa = new imageDownload_fewfiles();
DataOutputStream outputstream2 = new DataOutputStream(outputstream);
outputstream2.writeBytes("!@###!@###");
outputstream2.write(aa.image_files());
outputstream2.writeBytes("!@###!@###");
```

android :

```
 InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream();
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(http.getInputStream());
```

Is possible this way?? if possible , how i get a each byteArray from inputStream??

Please give me some advice.. I do not want to use a third-part

Comment: Just make a loop reading chunks from that inputstream. Add the chuncks to a byte array or save to file directly. Before adding check if the separator is received (you might receive only a few bytes of the separater).

Comment: It woulf be a much easier protocol if you send the size in bytes of the bytearray first. Instead of a separator. If The receiver receives the size of the byte array first its much easier to read just as much bytes in a loop as indicated.

Comment: WHy do you want to make Bitmaps out of the received dat? Will cost you a lot of memory. What are you going to do with them?

Comment: i want to show images on adroid . i have used bitmapfactory.decodestream() but it seems that bitmpfactory.decodestream()  is used as many as number of files .. i think this way is not good. So, i want to get some advise before i try to posted way

Comment: I gave you advise but you are not reacting. Also you tell too little about showing images.

Comment: sorry.
What I am creating an application that is published with the text and images.
One article, I would like to show a connection once there is a lot of images and text about them.
but Many examples can look at the number of server connections is dependent on the number of files show.  So the modifycation text and images in byteArray, trying to restore the stream was sent at a time. The Best way is sending length of each file and text , As you said?? is there difficult to separate the byte array using the separator?? or this way is shown bad performance??

Comment: You can answer that question yourself now as i already exactly told you what the problem was: `Instead of a separator. If The receiver receives the size of the byte array first its much easier to read just as much bytes in a loop as indicated. `.

Comment: But i wonder why you just wont do one connection per image. What's the problem doing it easy and fast?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you get the input stream correctly.

```
int length; // This should be get from the request.
byte[] array = new byte[length]; 
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
dataInputStream.readFully(array);
```

Comment: Thanks~ but how can i get each file byteArray ?? Because each file is loaded into a single stream byteArray

Comment: @tokhi It depends on how use put files into the stream but one simple way is to pass a list of integers that represents the length of each file. Then, you can separate the array by the integers.

Comment: I think also that sending the length of each file. but I will try to send with text using sigle outputstream. So, i think separator is required to know the length of each file and text byteArray. Am I mistaken?